# Comparator.nullsLast does not avoid NullPointerException

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, comparator

I want to sort a list of objects by one of nullable fields.

In order to avoid `NullPointerexception` I use `Comparator.nullsLast`. But the exception still occurs:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Bean> l = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            Bean b = new Bean("name_"+i,i);
            l.add(b);
        }
        l.get(2).setVal(null);
        System.out.println(l);
        Collections.sort(l, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(Bean::getVal)));
        System.out.println(l);
    }

    static class Bean{
        String name;
        Integer val;
        // omit getters & setters & constructor
    }

}
```

How can I sort this kind of list?

Comment: @rellocswood Please, post your solution as an answer instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You should use `Comparator.nullsLast` twice:

```
list.sort(nullsLast(comparing(Bean::getVal, nullsLast(naturalOrder()))));
```

- First `nullsLast` will handle the cases when the `Bean` objects are null.
- Second `nullsLast` will handle the cases when the return value of `Bean::getVal` is null.

In case you're sure there aren't any `null` values in your list then you can omit the first `nullsLast` (as noted by @Holger) :

```
list.sort(comparing(Bean::getVal, nullsLast(naturalOrder())));
```

Comment: Or omit the outer `nullsLast` if the beans are never `null`, i.e. only the property values might be `null`.

Answer (score 15):

You can possibly use :

```
Collections.sort(l, Comparator.comparing(Bean::getVal,
                              Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can review this example

```
@Override
public int compare(Example o1, Example o2) {
  if (o1 == null && o2 == null) return 0;
  if (o1 == null) return -1;
  if (o2 == null) return 1;
 return Comparator.comparing(Example::getSta,
      Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
      .thenComparing(Example::getId,
          Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
      .compare(o1, o2);
}

class Example {
String sta; Long id;}
```