# Comparator.comparing(((Function<Entity, SubEntity>)Entity::getSubEntity).andThen(SubEntity::getAmount)));

Tags: java-8, comparator

what if SubEntity is null, some of of SubEntity itself null then SubEntity::getAmount null pointer so how to avoid

Comment: Your code becomes far more readable when not trying to use method references at all costs: `Comparator.comparing(entity -> entity.getSubEntity().getAmount())`. The policy for null must be defined by you. E.g. treat them as smallest or largest value or just forbid them and throw an exception. I recommend the latter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparator.nullsLast does not avoid NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314193/comparator-nullslast-does-not-avoid-nullpointerexception)

Answer (score 1):

use [Comparator.nullsLast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast-java.util.Comparator-)

```
Comparator.nullsLast(
  Comparator.comparing(((Function<Entity, SubEntity>)Entity::getSubEntity)
            .andThen(SubEntity::getAmount))));
```