# NullPointerException when using Comparator with nullsLast

Tags: java, list, sorting, nullpointerexception, comparator

I know there are many similar questions about the same issue. However, I've tried the solutions provided and none worked for me. I am 100% sure it is something basic I am missing, but I am not able to find what is wrong, hence asking it here...

I have a custom object like this:

```
public class ClassA {
    private int id;
    private Integer min1;
    private Integer min2;
}
```

In another class (`ClassB`) I have a list of `ClassA` objects that I need to sort. First items should be those who have a lower value in any of the `min` properties. In case two objects have the same value, then does not matter which one goes first. For example, if I have these objects:

| ID | min1 | min1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | null |
| 2 | null | 30 |
| 3 | 80 | null |
| 4 | 23 | null |
| 5 | 10 | null |

Order should be (ID): 1, 5, 4, 2, 3.

To achieve this I have a method that returns a `Comparator`:

```
public static Comparator<ClassA> compareMins(Function<ClassA, Integer> min) {
    return Comparator.comparing(minuto, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
}
```

In `ClassB` I get the Comparator and sort the list as follows:

```
Comparator<ClassA> comparator = ClassA.compareMins(ClassA::getMin1)
    .thenComparing(ClassA::getMin2);
lista.sort(comparator);
```

However, it is throwing a `NullPointerException` when comparing objects ID `1` and `5`. I guess that as `min1` has the same value, it tries to compare min2, which are null, and hence, throwing this exception. However, I am unable to find a solution to this. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Regarding, "*I know there are many similar questions about the same issue. However, I've tried the solutions provided and none worked for me.*", if you've seen these similar questions, then you should know that with this type of question you will want to show the exception stack trace, indicate the offending line, and indicate which variable on that line is null when the exception is thrown. Also, indicate why you think that the variable should not be null, and where you initialize it.

Comment: Please explain why you expect the order to be 1, 5, 4, 2, 3. I'd expect 2 to come last when sorting by min1.

Comment: Reopening, because this is not really about NullPointerException itself, but rather how to use Comparator.nullsLast (and nullsFirst).

Comment: @VGR: understood. Would [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314193/comparator-nullslast-does-not-avoid-nullpointerexception) be a better duplicate?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels There is some overlap, but that seems to be a more complicated case.  And I see that many of the (unaccepted) answers make the same mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Programming isn't magic and it isn't like humans. "Do what I mean" is not how it works.

> ```
> Comparator<ClassA> comparator = ClassA.compareMins(ClassA::getMin1)
>    .thenComparing(ClassA::getMin2);
> lista.sort(comparator);
> ```

This dutifully does exactly what you wrote, which is not what you meant. The `nullsLast` logic is applied by what `compareMins` does. You then chain `thenComparing(ClassA::getMin2)` which, rather obviously, **does not do any nulls last**. How could it? The compiler can't sniff out that 'hey, `compareMins` appears to do some nullsLast magic, do I think the programmer *intended* for the same nullsLast logic to apply to `getMin2`? Eh, I'll take a wild stab in the dark: Probably yeah so I'll just do that'.

Not, obviously, how compilers work.

By default all comparators NPE on nulls because nulls do not have any obvious ordering, and optimally don't even have an ordering between themselves (null is neither above nor below nor equal to any other `null` - `null` is best treated as 'unknown'. Given 2 unknown values it is not possible to say which one is higher or lower, nor is it possible to decree that they are equal).

You can fix it in the style you've been going so far but the style you've chosen doesn't sound right.

A much more obvious way to go is to make a method or function that does the job of 'return the lower of these 2 values, ignoring nulls'. Which isn't something the standard library has; it's a programming language where you program what you want. It's not a box of lego bricks where the job consists solely of finding the right bricks and snapping them together. Sometimes you gotta make your own, so to speak.

```
class classA {
 ....

 public int getLowest() {
   return
     min1 == null ? min2 :
     min2 == null ? min1 :
     Math.min(min1, min2);
 }
}

listA.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(ClassA::getLowest));
```

This fails only if **both** `min1` and `min2` are `null` for any instance of ClassA. Crashing is probably correct (it seems arbitrary / an error of attempting to blast right past the problem that something isn't known), but if you don't want that, you'd go with:

```
class classA {
 ....

 public Integer getLowest() {
   return
     min1 == null ? min2 :
     min2 == null ? min1 :
     Math.min(min1, min2);
 }
}

listA.sort(
  Comparator.comparing(
    ClassA::getLowest,
    Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've forgotten to use your nulls comparator `compareMins` a second time:

```
Comparator<ClassA> comparator = compareMins(ClassA::getMin1)
                 .thenComparing(compareMins(ClassA::getMin2));
```

As you have it now, using `.thenComparing(ClassA::getMin2)`, would evaluate the two instances of `min2` and would call `a.min2.compareTo(b.min2)` rather than the nulls friendly check you have created in `compareMins`. Hence `NullPointerException`.

Also, you have mixed `min` and `minuto` in the declaration of `compareMins`, this could be source of NPE => replace `minuto` with `min`.

```
public static Comparator<ClassA> compareMins(Function<ClassA, Integer> min) {
    return Comparator.comparing(min, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

}